# Overflow Error #6 VBA while using long data type

Tags: vba, excel, integer-overflow

New to VBA coming from Python so it is quit the difference.

```
Sub Average_Income()

    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim avg As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Total As Long
    Dim Bottom As Long
    Dim Low As Long
    Dim Mid As Long
    Dim Mid_High As Long
    Dim High As Long
    Dim Top As Long
    Dim Number As Long


    Set data = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set avg = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Averages")

    Total = CLng(7)
    Bottom = CLng(8)
    Low = CLng(9)
    Mid = CLng(10)
    Mid_High = CLng(11)
    High = CLng(12)
    Top = CLng(13)

    For i = 2 To 1000
        Number = avg.Cells(i, 2)
        CLng(Number) = CLng(data.Cells(Total, 19).Value) / CLng(data.Cells(Total, 18).Value)
        Total = Total + 8
    Next i
End Sub
```

I feel like I have tried everything! What is going on?

Comment: You shouldn't use `CLng` on the left side of the = operator. Which line causes the error and what are the relevant cell values when it happens?

Comment: This may/may not be an issue, could setting the one variable as a Double, be the solution, because of decimal points?

Comment: If `data.Cells(Total, 18).Value` contains zero (0) you will always get the overflow error.

Comment: The error is happening with the line that reads CLng(Number) = CLng(data.Cells(Total, 19).Value) / CLng(data.Cells(Total, 18).Value)

Comment: @SkyMaster Not true, only if `CLng(data.Cells(Total, 19).Value)` is also 0. For only`CLng(data.Cells(Total, 18).Value)` equal 0 there will be division by 0 error.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow is an error in division 0 / 0.

Other divisions by 0 generate Run-time Error 11: Division by zero.

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print 0 / 0
End Sub
```